# What is a good way to pass in Entity Types into a constructor for a generic class, such that the entity name can be used within a ctor LINQ query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using MVC3, C#, Razor and EF 5.

I am building a generic class that can take in different Entities within its constructor ie "Order" so my calling code may look like. I have just realised that I only need to pass in a type name and not a object instance, so what would this look like:

```
ef_generic my_ef_generic = new ef_generic("Test",Order)
```

Currently my ctor signature looks like. This is wrong since I need to pass in a type:

```
public ef_generic(string strName, object objEntity)
```

I need to access this "ObjEntity" in a LINQ query ie:

db.objEntity.Where(e=>e.id==myId).First().Name

Finally I would like to define a private type using the type of the objEntity, so far I have:

```
    private List<object> _myRecords;
    public List<object> myRecords
    {
```

So I want to pass in an explicit Entity Framework Type into a generic class for use, and I am asking as to what a good approach would be.

Many thanks.

Comment: You using code first or database first?

Comment: Model First :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest is to make your class a generic; see the below as pseudo code that you can change around to your liking, not as a style guide :)

```cs
public class ef_generic<T> where T : class, IHaveAnIdAndAName
{
    private List<T> _myRecords;          // Your internal List
    public IEnumerable<T> myRecords { 
      get { return _myRecords; } 
    }                                    // Public list getter
    private string _result;

    public ef_generic(string strName, IQueryable<T> objEntity)
    {
        const int myId = 4;
        _result = objEntity.First(e => e.Id == myId).Name;
        //...
    }
}
```

Note that the entity type (here `TestEntity`) you want to pass in needs an Id and a Name for the linq query, so it needs to promise to implement that using the interface `IHaveAnIdAndAName`; also, as Slauma points out in the comments, it needs to have a class constraint also.

```
public interface IHaveAnIdAndAName
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}

public class TestEntity : IHaveAnIdAndAName { ...
```

When you want to instantiate the class, pass it the IQueryable collection from the context instead of the type name (it's hard to guess which collection from the type name, so easier to do the other way)

```
Db db = GetDb();
var test = new ef_generic<TestEntity>("test", db.TestEntities);
```

Comment: This is excellent. Hugely appreciate the comprehensive answer.

Comment: You must add a `class` constraint for the generic type: `where T : class, IHaveAnIdAndAName`. Otherwise LINQ to Entities will throw a `NotSupportedException` at the `First` query complaining that it does not support converting `TestEntity` into `IHaveAnIdAndAName`.